# Respond to HTTP request in AWS Lambda before running all code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I've built a Lambda function that can be triggered by an HTTP request (via the API Gateway). It integrates with my bank, so the bank sends me an HTTP request every time a transaction occurs on my account. If I don't respond with a 200 code within 10 seconds, the bank sends the request again.

My Lambda function runs typically for half a minute or so, meaning that often it gets triggered multiple times since I don't respond back to the bank on time.

Is there a way to send a 200 status code back before running the major workload of my lambda function? I guess one of the ways could be to have two lambda functions running, one triggering the other one asynchronously and responding in time, though I would prefer to keep it in a single lambda function.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # DO STUFF THAT TAKES approx 20-30 seconds
    event_body = json.loads(event["body"])
    # more stuff

    # RETURN THIS CODE EARLIER
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

Comment: Yes, set the lambda up as async: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html - alternatively, have the lambda do *some* quick word, then put a message onto a queue, respond to the request and let a different lambda handle the long running part off of the queue.

Comment: When you receive the request add it to SNS or SQS and send a response 200 to the back later you can process the messages in SNS or SQS and store the process output

Comment: Note that stuff that takes 30 seconds is inherently ill-suited for api gateway since api gateway automatically timeouts after 30 seconds.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear on what you can do?

Comment: Yep, makes total sense. Haven't had the time to try it, but giving it a spin tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  problem requires **two functions**. But instead of the second one being asynchronously invoked from the first one, it would be better to de-couple them using SQS queue.

So the first function send message to the **SQS queue** and returns 200.
The second function gets automatically message from the queue and performs processing:

```
API gateway --> Lambda 1 ---> SQS queue ---> Lambda 2
```